# Getting the length of Flatlist in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flatlist

I am trying to get the total length of the flatlist. I searched and found that we can use onLayout to get the value of the event.nativeEvent.layout.height to get the height of the Flatlist.

But when I try to get the height of the flatlist, it is giving me a constant value irrespective of the number of items in the flatlist. For example for iphone14 pro max simulator it is giving me a constant value of 839 in both cases when data has 10 elements or 1 element. Can you guide me on how to get the actual length of the list?

Any help in this matter will be greatly appreciated.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "lightgreen" }}>
  <FlatList
    onLayout={event => {
      console.log(
        "height of list",
        event.nativeEvent.layout.height,
        Dimensions.get("screen").height
      );
    }}
    contentContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}
    data={[12, 35, 45, 78, 89, 56]}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
      return <Text>{item}</Text>;
    }}
    keyExtractor={item => item}
  />
</View>
```

The text in console is displayed as

> height of list 826.9091186523438 850.9090909090909

[image]

The image here shows the flatlist length in red and the green background as the overall view.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of items in a FlatList component, you can use the `data.length` property. The `data` prop of the FlatList component is an array of data that you want to render in the list, and the length property of an array gives you the number of items in it.

In your case data = [12, 35, 45, 78, 89, 56]

Example-

```
const numberOfItems = data.length;

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Number of items: {numberOfItems}</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

In order to get the length/height of the actual list:

```
const onFlatListLayout = (event) => {
    console.log(event.nativeEvent.layout.height) //this will give the list length/height
  };

<FlatList
      data={/* your data */}
      renderItem={/* your renderItem function */}
      onLayout={onFlatListLayout} //add this
    />
```

Comment: Hey Shivani, I am not looking for the length of data but the length of the actual list for example like 1200px or something like that.

Comment: In order to get the length of the actual list:

const onFlatListLayout = (event) => {
    console.log(event.nativeEvent.layout.height) //this will give the list length/height
  };

<FlatList
      data={/* your data */}
      renderItem={/* your renderItem function */}
      onLayout={onFlatListLayout} //add this
    />